# swift core data relationship retrieving object

Tags: swift, core-data, relationship

I am using core data to manage my data.  For example I have a `Car` class and a `CartPart` class.  `Car`s to `CarPart`s represents a one to many relationship.  Each `Car` can have many `CarPart`s, but each `CarPart` can only have one parent `Car`.

When I create a `CarPart` I assign the `myCarpart` a `Car` using the following code.  (`carRelationship` is the name of the relationship in my Core Data Model).

```
myCartPart.carRelationship = myCar
```

But when I go to retrieve the relationship in code later using:

```
myCar = myCarPart.carRelationship!
```

I get the following error

> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

and I'm not sure why

Car & CarPart are subclasses of NSManagedObject.   Here is how I create it and attach a Car object to it.

```
do {

            myCarPart = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("CarPart", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! CarPart

            myCarPart.carRelationship = myCar
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
```

here is how i try to retrieve it:
         carParts = result as! [CarPart]

```
            var carPart : CarPart!

            var car : Car

            for c in carParts {

                carPart = bid as! CarPart

                car = carPart.carRelationship! //call returns nil

                self.cars.append(car)
```

}

Comment: you need to give more details on what the `myCarPart` is, when you create it, update it, save those changes, query the object (maybe query it back from the store)...

Comment: @Wain, updated my question to reflect when I create and query myCarPart.  Thanks

Comment: Could you check if `myCar` is nil when you assigned it to `carRelationship`?

Comment: @EricQian I just checked: myCar is not nil upon assignment, but it is nil upon retrieval.

Comment: What is `bid`?  Do you mean `carPart = c as! CarPart`?

Comment: Hey guys, turns out I myCar was corrupt data from an older build.  I deleted all the old data and it works fine now.  Thanks for your input.